# Why is my Angular service not returning data

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-services

I am using https://github.com/StarterSquad/startersquad.github.com/tree/master/examples/angularjs-requirejs-2 folder structure for app and inside services and I have following code:

```
define(['./module'], function(services) {
'use strict';
services.factory('user_resources', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location) {

        return $resource("", {},
                {
                    'getAll': {method: "GET", url:'JSON/myList.JSON',isArray:true}

                });
    }]);
});
```

and in controller I have following code:

```
  define(['./module'],    function (controllers) {
'use strict';
controllers.controller('myListCtrl',['Phone','Phone1','loginForm','$scope','$http','user_resources','CreditCard',function(Phone,Phone1,loginForm,$scope,$http,user_resources,CreditCard){
    console.log(user_resources.getAll())
}]);
});
```

which returns [$promise: Object, $resolved: false] how to get data from that?

I have done the same thing which is done in 
[this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11), but in my case it returns promises and in tutorial it directly returns data

Comment: it returns a promise - `user_resources.getAll().then(function(data) { //here is your data})`

Comment: i have tried this but error says TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> myListCtrl.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a `$resource` returns you an object immediately, before the data is retrieved from the server. This object has a property called `$promise`. When the response is finally received from the server, the `$promise` gets resolved and the object will now contain the data.

In your case the `console.log()` output prints what it does because you're accessing the object immediately, before the server has had a chance to respond.

You can do several things with the object returned by `$resource`:

1) Use it in your views in Angular expressions. When the `$promise` gets resolved automatically the view will be updated with no effort on your part. For example:

controller:

```
$scope.users = user_resources.getAll();
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

2) Use the `then()` function as suggested by @doodeec above, but with the correct syntax:

```
user_resources.getAll().$promise.then(function(data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, a promise is returned from all the $http services and you need to handle the response instead of the execution.

An example of a similar problem and solution can be seen here:  http://angularspot.com/topic/11-post-not-returning-data-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

Remember to $httpBackend.flush(), the promise will not be resolved until then.